# C# Marshal.Sizeof() when using custom marshaler

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

Is it possible to use *Marshal.SizeOf()* on a structure which is using a custom marshaler?

For example:

```
struct Abcde { 
  public int test1;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(MyCustomMarshaler)]
  public string customString1;
}
```

If I call:

```
var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Abcde));
```

an exception is thrown which says that no meaningful size or offset can be computed.
I noticed that *ICustomMarshaler* has a method called *GetNativeDataSize()* but the exception is thrown regardless what I return there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Marshal.SizeOf` cannot be used with types that contain custom marshaled members.

Comment: Is there a reference for this assertion? I concur (via empirical experimental observation), but would love to see some authoritative explanation, status, reasoning, etc. Will this be fixed in future, for example?

Comment: It's pretty obvious why this is so, surely.  I'm not sure that anything needs to be fixed. This appears to be working as designed.

Comment: Thanks for following up my comment on an old thread, David. I'm not sure why it should be obvious; it's not to me: I might reasonably think that `Marshal.SizeOf` would invoke my `ICustomMarshaler.GetNativeDataSize` implementation, but it does not. To me, it's not obvious why this is.

Comment: @kkahl The documentation says: *Because custom marshaling of value types is not supported in the .NET Framework, this method always returns -1.*